# Edit richtextbox to keep only words that contains underscore

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I need some help to define how I can edit the text in the RichTextBox.
For example, I will paste the following text in the RichTextBox:

```
"Release to user USER the roles: ZBR_POA_FIL_APOIO_GESTAO, ZBR_REC_FIL_SUPPORT, ZBR_RJO_CD_FIL_SUPPORT, ZBR_SVD_CD_FIL_SUPPORT, Z_GENERAL_OBJECTS, Z_DEBUG, Z_CHECK"
```

Then I want to edit this to keep only the text that contains the underscore `_`, and separate them in a new line, like this:

```
ZBR_POA_FIL_APOIO_GESTAO
ZBR_REC_FIL_SUPPORT
ZBR_RJO_CD_FIL_SUPPORT
ZBR_SVD_CD_FIL_SUPPORT
Z_GENERAL_OBJECTS
Z_DEBUG
Z_CHECK
```

I guess I should probably use regex for this, but I didn't have much luck with it.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes Jerry, I've tried many things already, but the only thing I've managed to do is break every space in a new line (which don't have any secret actually), now I want to only keep the lines that contains the underscore, remove the lines which doesn't have, and then remove the empty lines. The thing I need most is: How to keep only the lines that contains the underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = @"Release to user USER the roles: ZBR_POA_FIL_APOIO_GESTAO, ZBR_REC_FIL_SUPPORT, ZBR_RJO_CD_FIL_SUPPORT, ZBR_SVD_CD_FIL_SUPPORT, Z_GENERAL_OBJECTS, Z_DEBUG, Z_CHECK";
var words = text.Split(new[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var wordsWithUnderscores = words.Where(o => o.Contains("_")).ToArray();

foreach(var word in wordsWithUnderscores) {
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luis.
Much more simple than I thought.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string FormatString(string s)
{
String[] array=Regex.Matches(@"\b(?=\w*_)\w+\b",s)
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray();
return String.Join("\n",array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anirudh.

I'm not going to use this function right now, but it helped me to understand more the Regex and this will be very helpfull for me in the future.

Best regards,
Paulo Rocha